# Rounded Corners of an Embedded UITextView – What Is (Incorrectly) Keeping the Corners Opaque?

Tags: ios, uitextview, transparency, rounded-corners, uicontainerview

NOTE: I edited this for clarity after figuring out the solution (below).

In interface builder, I embedded a UIView within another UIView and linked them to their respective UIViewControllers, EmbeddedViewController and MainViewController. Then I put a UITextView into the embedded UIView and created a reference to it in EmbeddedViewController.

In MainViewController I programmatically set `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray`. In the EmbeddedViewController I set `textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white` and `textView.layer.cornerRadius = 50`. Using those colors, it appeared that the corners hadn't been rounded. But when I set `textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`, it was obvious that the rounding worked, but that the corners *of something* were opaque white. The problem is, I don't know what that something is, and after trying out several possibilities, I still don't know what I need to fix.

None of the prior questions seem to have dealt with this particular problem (i.e., non-transparency around the rounded corners of a UITextView in an embedded UIView), but if I missed something, please brow beat me for not trying hard enough. Otherwise, I'd be happy with either an interface builder or a programmatic solution.

Here's an image (per request), in which `textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`:

[image]

Comment: try clip to bounds set true for textview

Comment: Any screenshots?

Comment: I tried that (again), canister_exister. `textView.clipsToBounds = true` had no effect.

Comment: Glenn, I guess the picture does make the problem seem somehow more tangible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I incorrectly thought that I had embedded a UITextView, when in fact I embedded a UIView that *contained* a UITextView. So instead of two views to deal with, there are actually three: the MainViewController's view, the EmbeddedViewController's view, and the EmbeddedViewController's textView. So to round the corners of the UITextView, here's a reasonable approach:

In EmbeddedViewController, set `view.layer.cornerRadius = 50` and set `view.clipsToBounds = true`. Since the UITextView is a subview of the embedded UIView, textView gets clipped to the bounds of view.

With that, the above white regions are no more.